# Accidentally send BCH to my CashApp wallet!

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I accidentally had my Forex broker send BCH instead of BTC to my CashApp (I chose the wrong option for withdrawal) It ended up at a Bitcoin address which only lists the transaction meaninig on the "explorer" site). I don't have a wallet with Bitcoin.com .
How can I get my funds to my cashapp? I have been chasing Cashapp for 5 days now and they are not responding to my request properly. Is there a way? Or do I have to wait on cashapp to recover the funds and put it my cash app wallet? $1600 is a lot of money to lose!
Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The [only one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/62456/5406) that can help you is CashApp, since you locked your funds to a key they control. AFAIK, CashApp uses segwit addresses, and BCH does not support segwit, so recovery would require a bunch of additional (likely manual) intervention. You'll have to negotiate with them.

Comment: I think she needs a miner and the wallet devs would be unlikely to help. SegWit is anyonecanspend in BCH.

Comment: It's anyonecanspend, but you still need to know the redeemscript to solve the hashpuzzle.

Answer (score 0):

If your address is a SegWit `3...` address as Murch said, then you would have to

- Make a transaction from the wallet (for this, you need to send a little amount of BTC sent to the address)
- Find a miner that you can trust (Reddit? r/bitcoincash) and give them the TXID
- They'll DEDUCT a percentage fee (don't pay them! that would sound like a scam) before sending you your coins (I have seen a miner deducting only 10%)

The hardest part is *finding a miner* that you can trust.

Comment: You also need to know the redeemscript so you can solve the hashpuzzle that's left to resolve the spending conditions remaining on the stack when you try to spend segwit on BCH. If CashApp has not used the address before, then the redeemscript is a secret only CashApp knows.

Comment: You're right. Depositing to that address and spending from it doesn't guarantee revealing the redeemscript